# how bootstrap recognize code for mobile viewport?

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<!-- The above 3 lined is used to make the webpage  responsive -->

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-control="navbar"> navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>

 </button>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contents</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>

    <header class="jumbotron row-header">

        <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best 
cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking 
creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row  row-content ">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9"> 
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align="center">Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs12 col-sm-9  col-sm-pull-3">
                <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
                <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and
 Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes,
 Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
                <p><a href="#">More »</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row  row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align="center">This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
                <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of
 five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and 
five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for 
just $19.99 per person </p>
                <p><a href="#">More »</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <h3 align="center">Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
                <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide 
International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the 
culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian 
fusion experiences. </p>
                <p><a href="#">More »</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="row-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">             
                <div class="col-xm-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                   </address>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
                        <a href="mailto:">Mail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align="center">Â© Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
      <!-- jquery (necessery for bootstrap javascript plugin) -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body></html>



Can anyone tell me how Bootstrap recognize that span button code is for mobile or for desktop how program recognize that the nav bar only visible when it viewport is for desktop and run button code when viewport is for mobile .what the logic behind?
```

Please tell me how bootstrap recognize code to be run on desktop and for mobile .what is the logic behind recognition of code in bootstrap for mobile viewport and for desktop. This is my course project for Bootstrap but i am confused in logic how bootstrap recognized code even though i did't mention in code.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3 Media Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are how CSS in general (and Bootstrap in particular) display differently on different media/screen sizes.  For example, the following lines in *bootstrap.css*

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    width: 540px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

say that on a screen size at least 576 pixels wide (Bootstrap's "small" device breakpoint), the `.container` style will have a width of 540 pixels.

Comment: i want to say if i don't mention the @media viewport commands in css then how it is possible for bootstrap to recognize code for the mobile and desktop code